# Property 'value' does not exist on type EventTarget (ts2339)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I am getting squigglies:

[image]

You can see I'm typing it right (I think).

```js
  const hClick = (e:React.MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement>)=>{
    console.log(e.target.value)
  }
```

Here's the element in question.

```
      {props.question.responses.map((r: string, i: number) => {
        return <button key={i} value={r} className={`${CSS.columnBtn} ${CSS.gray}`} onClick={(e) => hClick(e)}>{r}</button>;
      })}
```

You can see it clearly has a value. I also did my research. Not only do buttons have values natively but MS [said in their docs](https://microsoft.github.io/PowerBI-JavaScript/interfaces/_node_modules_typedoc_node_modules_typescript_lib_lib_dom_d_.htmlbuttonelement.html#value) they have a value prop as does the [general button element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button#attr-value) per Mozilla and when I ctrl + clicked into the d.ts file for HTMLButtonElement, it shows a value prop that's a string:

```js
    /**
     * Sets or retrieves the default or selected value of the control.
     */
    value: string;
```

Morever the code works and it logs the value. I'm pretty new to TypeScript so there's probably something I don't know, and that's what I want to learn.

BTW if a property doesn't exist in a given element but you give it a custom one, it obviously won't be in the d.ts so how would you tell the compiler that your html attribute foo[="bar"] exists on the event?

Comment: What if you use `currentTarget` instead?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Since `target` could be any other potential element (or even a non-element) you can use a Type Assertion to make it into `HTMLButtonElement`.

```
const hClick = (e:React.MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement>)=>{
    let button = e.target as HTMLButtonElement;
    console.log(button.value)
}
```

I look on the React Typings and the `HTMLButtonElement` will end up in `currentTarget` (which makes sense because that's the element the listener is attached to which is a button).

So you can just use:

```
const hClick = (e:React.MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement>)=>{
    console.log(e.currentTarget.value)
}
```

Comment: I tried your first suggestion and it worked but as far as creating the button object, I thought the whole point of e:React.MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement> was to tell compiler the object type so that intermediary is not necessary. What is the point otherwise? I tried your second suggestion and it didn't create new errors but the first error stayed.

Comment: Yes, but the `HTMLButtonElement` interface will not be used for `target` since the event target can be other element. The type will use that (`HTMLButtonElement`) for its `currentTarget` typing. You still have the same error with `currentTarget`?

Comment: It likes currentTarget!     ```console.log(e.currentTarget.value)```. I'm in new concept space now. I think I get what you mean. If you click an element, are you really clicking that element, or are you clicking the parent of the element or the child of that element? Is that right? I have to read more about currentTarget.

Comment: Yes, `target` could very well be a child element while `currentTarget` will always be the element the listener was attached to.

Answer (score 2):

**<input (keyup)="myeventreal($any($event).target.value)" />**

use this in angluar 13 version